# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)

Tags: python

```
def __str__(self):
    summa = 0
    for a in self.__pisteet:
        summa += a
        mjono += str(a)
    return "{:s} {:s} yhteensa", summa, "pistetta".format(self.__nimi, mjono)
```

So there are multiple players and I should be able to print all their names, all scores and the sum of scores.

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

Answer (score 6):

Items separated by commas create a tuple, so you need to remove those:

```
return "{:s} {:s} yhteensa {} pistetta".format(self.__nimi, mjono, summa)
```

Comment: Okey it worked thanks! I wouldn´t have thought that that was the problem.

Comment: @user3351375 Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not returning a string, take a look to your return statement. ',' comma operator defines a tuple it does not concatenate strings, you must return:

```
return "{:s} {:s} yhteensa {} pistetta".format(self.__nimi, mjono,  summa)
```